# Using two different, but very similar, layouts causes android:ImeOptions="ActionNext" to not work

Tags: android, android-xml, imeoptions

I have two layouts, one for portait and the other for landscape, that pass information on to the next field. The two use identical source code, and similar XML code. One of them shows the "next" button where I would expect, the other shows the "done" button. FrequencyEnterField is a FrameLayout. The one that works uses this XML code:

```
        <com.kd7uiy.hamfinder.dialogs.FrequencyEnterField
            android:id="@+id/freq"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/modeSelect" />
```

And the one that doesn't uses this code:

```
        <com.kd7uiy.hamfinder.dialogs.FrequencyEnterField
            android:id="@+id/freq"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/modeSelect" />
```

The difference is because the horizontal one evenly divides space across the screen, while the vertical one doesn't need to do that. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `android:nextFocusForward` instead of `android:nextFocusDown`. It seems that `nextFocusForward` is used for the IME "Next" button. It may just happen to work in one orientation due to the way the layout is interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work via a bit of a hack. The FrequencyEnterField is a container for either a spinner or an EditText, depending on the settings. If it's an EditText, I manually specify the action in code as an IME_ACTION_NEXT,

```
mFreqEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```

And that seems to do the trick...